# How do I update model value in javascript from asp.net core view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to drag and drop child entities (unit) to different parents (user). How can I access the corresponding child entity and update its parent in the javascript drop event?

```
@foreach (var user in Model.Users)
{
    <div class="card w-75">
        <div class="card-body" id="@user.Id">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
                <li class="list-group-item">Units</li>
                @foreach (var unit in user.Units)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="@unit.Id">@unit.Id</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
        if (ev.target.localName == 'li') {
            ev.target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', document.getElementById(data));
            @Model.Units.First(u => u.Id == data).OwnerId = ev.target.parentElement.parentElement.ID;
        }
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

The variable "data" is not accessible like this, and I don't know if I can call into @Model in the first place.

Comment: Use the ViewData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know if I can call into @Model in the first place.

You cann't do that directly. The`@Model.Units.First(u => u.Id == data).OwnerId = ev.target.parentElement.parentElement.ID;` runs on server side. Before someone drags & drops the `<li>` element, **the server side code has already been executed** (rendered). **It's not possible to make them run on client side**.

To achieve your goals, you need send a `HTTP` request to the server when someone drags & drops the `<li>` element. In order to avoid too much HTTP requests, you could create a `modelCache` variables that stores the `Unit-Owner` map, and changes this `modelCache` in `drop(ev)` function:

```
<script>
    var modelCache = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        Model.Units.Select(u => new { UnitId = u.Id , OwnerId = u.OwnerId})
    ));

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
        let ownerId= ev.target.parentElement.parentElement.id
        if (ev.target.localName == 'li') {
            ev.target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', document.getElementById(data));
            modelCache.filter(u => u.UnitId == data)[0].OwnerId = ownerId; 
        }
        console.log(modelCache);
        // when you decide to submit, send the modelCache to the server action : `UpdateUnitOwner(modelCache)`
        // document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Finally, you'll need a server side action/handler to receive the ajax request:

```
IActionResult UpdateUnitOwner(List<UnitOwnerMap> maps)
{ 
    // ...  update the databse
}
```

In this way, you could update the `Unit-Owner` relationship by simply dragging and dropping.